# Attempt to display json contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is the JSON Content I am referring to :

```
{
  "webservice_status": {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": ""
  },
  "dailyroster": [
    {
      "webservice_status": null,
      "recordNumber": "3014973",
      "first_date": "2016-04-27",
      "first_recordType": "BM Specimen",
      "record_id": 0

    },
    {
      "webservice_status": null,
      "recordNumber": "3014973",
      "first_date": "2016-04-27",
      "first_recordType": "BM Specimen",
      "record_id": 0

    },
    {
      "webservice_status": null,
      "recordNumber": "3014973",
      "first_date": "2016-04-27",
      "first_recordType": "BM Specimen",
       "record_id": 0

    }

  ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve information using jQuery AJAX call inside the `fetchInfo` function defined below:

```
this.fetchInfo = function (recordNumber_,recordType_,recordDate_) {

        // some code here


        var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({

            data: {
                record_id: rg.record.id,
                recordNumber: recordNumber_,
                first_recordType: recordType_,
                first_date: recordDate_

            },
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            url: url
        })
        .done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {

            // some code

           var json_contents = data_.dailyroster;

           console.log("Attempt to display Doc Contents: "+json_contents[1]);

           // some code below

        }

    }
```

Here is the message in console log I keep on getting:

`Attempt to display Doc Contents: [object Object]`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are doing right.
json_contents is an instance of JsonArray.so that,json_contents[1] is an instance of JsonObject.you message in the console is right.
If you want to dispay your in detail,you should dispay them like this:
**json_content[1].webservice_status**